# How to grab other data inside class with Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

```
<svg aria-label="Unlike" class="_8-yf5 " color="#ed4956" fill="#ed4956" height="24" role="img" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="24"><path d="M34.6 3.1c-4.5 0-7.9 1.8-10.6 5.6-2.7-3.7-6.1-5.5-10.6-5.5C6 3.1 0 9.6 0 17.6c0 7.3 5.4 12 10.6 16.5.6.5 1.3 1.1 1.9 1.7l2.3 2c4.4 3.9 6.6 5.9 7.6 6.5.5.3 1.1.5 1.6.5s1.1-.2 1.6-.5c1-.6 2.8-2.2 7.8-6.8l2-1.8c.7-.6 1.3-1.2 2-1.7C42.7 29.6 48 25 48 17.6c0-8-6-14.5-13.4-14.5z"></path></svg>
```

I'm needing to grab `area-label="Unlike"` but can't figure out how. I've tried the following:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//svg[@class='_8-yf5 ''][@aria-label='Unlike']")
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with Java+Selenium and it worked,

HTML:

```
<html>

<body>
    <svg aria-label="Unlike" class="_8-yf5 " color="#ed4956" fill="#ed4956" height="24" role="img" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="24"><path d="M34.6 3.1c-4.5 0-7.9 1.8-10.6 5.6-2.7-3.7-6.1-5.5-10.6-5.5C6 3.1 0 9.6 0 17.6c0 7.3 5.4 12 10.6 16.5.6.5 1.3 1.1 1.9 1.7l2.3 2c4.4 3.9 6.6 5.9 7.6 6.5.5.3 1.1.5 1.6.5s1.1-.2 1.6-.5c1-.6 2.8-2.2 7.8-6.8l2-1.8c.7-.6 1.3-1.2 2-1.7C42.7 29.6 48 25 48 17.6c0-8-6-14.5-13.4-14.5z"></path></svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Java:

```
try {
            WebDriver driver;
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//chromedriver");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get("file:///home/milin/eclipse-workspace/ChannelErrorReports/demo/test.html");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("svg[class='_8-yf5 ']")).getAttribute("aria-label"));
            
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            driver.close();
            driver.quit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Replace the syntax of this line with Python:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("svg[class='_8-yf5 ']")).getAttribute("aria-label");
```

Answer (score -1):

Fixed with:

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".fr66n > button:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1) > svg:nth-child(1)").get_attribute("aria-label")
```